# Mathematica crashed, now my file's all in text. How do I get it back to normal?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

I was completing an assignment for a mathematica class, and ran a large set of data that crashed the program. I had to restart my computer, and when I relaunched mathematica, my file looks like this (attached). Does anyone know how to get it back to normal?

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlkPgrn2h3CjiX_DcE0n4Iz87duq?e=HE9Jx6

Comment: You can repair, within limits, a corrupted notebook file.  See:  https://support.wolfram.com/12423.

Comment: I tried Dominic's suggestion with your file; it's easy and it works! I'd suggest (to Dominic or you) posting it as an answer so that the question is resolved, even though it's short.